# Creating grid cell and associating to each row (point) by the cell id

Tags: qgis, csv, vector-grid, polygon-creation

I  have the following data in CSV format: latitude and longitude of the geolocation of different events, where they occurred, and different additional information. Each row is a different event with a different location or with the same. I also have a grid of cells.

The idea is to associated to each event with a cell according to their latitude and longitude. I would like to associate each point (each row) of the csv with a cell. Each point should get an additional attribute with the id of the cell. Not every cell in the grid have an event, so, this last cells should maintain without information, like missing or something.

Comment: You should not delete the old answer and create a new post as the old question already has an answer. Undelete the first question and delete this one.

Comment: @Babel You are making me a mess. How can I undelete the before question? I said apologies for it. It is my first question here. I just put again the question because I could not receive more answers and I did not put my question clear. I should have had more careful with it. Please, let me maintain this question. I will not do it again.

Comment: I voted to reopen the old questions. Let's see if there will be enough votes to do so, than I will post my answer there. You already have the grid and just want to know how to associate it's cells to the points? Or do you also need help creating the grid? Please always be as clear in your questions as possible. Posting a screenshot and stating what you already have, what you tried and at what point exactly you're stuck and how the result you want to achieve should look like helps a lot to understand where you need help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Babel. I do not have the grid, I have just the CSV I mention in the question. I need to create the grid. I edited a bit more my question, probably now it is clearer.

Comment: Even thought there will be enough votes, how can I undelete the question? I have been looking but I have not seen it anymore.

Comment: The answer posted by user @Kurt does not help to create the grid? Did you try these solutions, especially `Create grid` from Processingtoolbox (or also from Menu Vector / Research Tools / Create grid`? This should work.

Comment: The answer of @kurt was very good but I cannot see it anymore. I will try with Processingtoolbox. Is it possible to see my before question although I deleted it?

Comment: The original question seems gone, I can't find it anymore, so also the answer posted there seems lost. That's why you shouldn't delete the answer as @Kurt's efforts were in vain. So I will post an answer here.

Comment: I am sorry for it and thank you for the answers. I will apologyze with @kurt in by private message.

Comment: No private messages here an this site, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To create a grid: use `Menu Vector / Research Tools / Create grid`. Select rectangles (polygons), for the grid extent select the Africa-layer and set the horizontal and vertical distances (see screenshot 1).
2. Once you have the grid, assign to each of your points the `id` of the grid-cell it lies within. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Join attributes by position`, select the points and the grid as input and check the box to `within`.

You get a new layer - a copy of your initial points with additional attributes from the grid cell they lie within.

*Screenshot 1: create a grid*
[image]

*Screenshot 2: join attributes by position*
[image]

Comment: Thank you Babel, I will try to do it and I will let you know if it works!.

Comment: I am trying to do it when you have tell me but I have a small problem. I have a layer of the of world and when I try to select just Africa it is a bit complicate because it includes the middle east. Do you know an easy way to do it? I am sorry but I am very new using QGIS. Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, when I select the distance, it does not appear for me "grad". I have just meters, kilometers, foots, miles and yards. What I should choose?

Comment: For your question about selecting Africa: this is another question, you should post it here as another question and tell exactly what kind of data you have, what you've tried and where you're stuck. Post a screenshot if possible. If you want to create a grid in degrees, you should select a geographic CRS, e.g. `EPSG:4326`, see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWd4H.png

Comment: Thank you Babel. How can I upload a screenshot? I am trying to do to write a new post but I am not able to do it.

Comment: Click the picture icon to upload an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWivF.png - or you can simply drag-and-drop an image to the question window

Comment: Thank you! I did my best with it. It is already published.

Comment: I have a small question in this part. When I do the join attributes by location, why I should tick the box of within instead for example, the box of interseca, in your case I think it is schneidel sich mit? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, probably in this case the result will be the same (I guess). The points both are **within** and **intersect** a polygon cell. If you have two polygons (like a buffer around the points), these might intersect the grid-cell, but are not (completely) within.